# changePSW function does not work

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

can you help out a beginner trying to learn PHP? I wrote a code for changing password without any validations yet, just to change it and it does not work. It's been days I've been trying and couldn't figure out what's wrong. Thanks in advance.
id is variable name in database where id is kept.
db connection is done with first line and it definitely works.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);


function changePSW()
{
    //$password = $_POST['currPassword']; // required
    $newPassword = $_POST['newPassword']; // required
    //$newPassword2 = $_POST['NewPassword2']; // required
    $newPasswordH = password_hash($newPassword, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    echo($newPassword);

    $id = $_SESSION['userID'];
    echo($id);
    // create PDO connection object
    $dbConn = new DatabaseConnection();
    $pdo = $dbConn->getConnection();

    try {
        $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1");
        $statement->bindParam(':id', $id);
        $statement->execute();

        $result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        echo "SADASDASD";

        // no user matching the email
        if (empty($result)) {
            $_SESSION['error_message'] = 'Couldnt find user';
            header('Location: /Online-store/userForm.php');
            return;
        }
        $sql = "UPDATE users SET password=:newPasswordH WHERE id = :id";

        // Prepare statement
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        echo "AFGHANIKO";
        // execute the query
        $update_status = $stmt->execute(array(':password' => $newPasswordH, ':id' => $id));
        echo "IHAAA";
        echo($update_status);
        if ($update_status === TRUE) {
            echo("Record updated successfully" . "\r\n");
            echo nl2br("\nPassword: ");
            echo ($newPassword);
            echo nl2br("\nHashed Password: ");
            echo ($newPasswordH);
            return true;
        } else {
            echo "Error updating record";
            die();

        }

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        // usually this error is logged in application log and we should return an error message that's meaninful to user
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
}


if($_SESSION['isLoggedIn'] == true) {

    require_once("database/DatabaseConnection.php");

    unset($_SESSION['success_message']);
    unset($_SESSION['error_message']);

    changePSW();

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$update_status = $stmt->execute(array(':newPasswordH' => $newPasswordH, ':id' => $id));
```

This is what I needed to have instead of

```
$update_status = $stmt->execute(array(':password' => $newPasswordH, ':id' => $id));
```